# How to develop flutter application with paid and non paid users functionality?

Tags: flutter

I am going to develop a flutter application with multiple subscriptions.
For example(pro ,plus, premium). Contents will be vary belongs to the users subscription. I do not have any kind of idea to do this. Any legend here to help. Provide me some idea to do this.

Comment: I think this question is too vague. Please ask a specific question, or else, first review some flutter open source applications to learn how other developers have designed their systems, and then maybe you can get an idea of how to do it. Afterwards, if there is something specific which you do not understand or are confused about, then ask it here.

Comment: Sorry sir.. I wasted a whole day by searching some applications to help me out.... It didn't work.  That's why am here...

Answer (score 0):

There are too many options. Very simple one is:
You can use a variable like prouser = false then if user purchase success it turn to true. After that in your application you can use it with if. For example
if(prouser) ..... ? ...,,

Comment: Thank u Sir..  As because of too new to flutter... Can u suggest me any tutorials or video link.. I got tired of surfing things.  Can u?